# How to make git show changed files between two revisions?

Tags: git

I'm only interested in which files are newly created/modified/deleted between two commits,

is there a way to get such information?

Answer (score 1):

```
git diff --name-only rev1 rev2
```

This will show only the names of files that were changed in some way between the two revisions.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ git diff revision1 revision2
```

Comment: It's showing more than I want,which is noise to me.